# How to index a query with many joins

Tags: mysql, query-performance, join, mysql-5.7, index-tuning

I have this query with [this schema](https://github.com/snurr-group/mofdb/blob/master/db/schema.rb) that takes ~8s on my laptop and longer on the vm running the service.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `mofs`.*
FROM `mofs`
         INNER JOIN `isotherms` ON `isotherms`.`mof_id` = `mofs`.`id`
         INNER JOIN `isodata` ON `isodata`.`isotherm_id` = `isotherms`.`id`
WHERE `mofs`.`hidden` = FALSE
  AND (isodata.gas_id in (24))
  AND (volumeA3 is not NULL and atomicMass is not NULL)
ORDER BY `mofs`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 100;
```

Essentially I join mofs->isotherms->isodata (all simple one-many relationships) and select only the mofs with isodata.gas_id present in a list supplied by the user `(24)` in this case but there could be 1-6 numbes here.

There are a few constant where conditions `mofs.hidden = false` `mofs.volumeA3 is not NULL` and `mofs.atomicMass is not NULL`  these are the same for every query.

I've tried adding an index `:mofs, [:volumeA3, :atomicMass, :hidden], where: 'volumeA3 IS NOT NULL and atomicMass IS NOT NULL and hidden is FALSE'` to capture the static part of the query. This doesn't make it notably faster.

Query explainer:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT `mofs`.* FROM `mofs`          INNER JOIN `isotherms` ON `isotherms`.`mof_id` = `mofs`.`id`          INNER JOIN `isodata` ON `isodata`.`isotherm_id` = `isotherms`.`id` WHERE `mofs`.`hidden` = FALSE   AND (isodata.gas_id in (24))   AND (volumeA3 is not NULL and atomicMass is not NULL) ORDER BY `mofs`.`id` ASC LIMIT 100;
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type | possible_keys                                                                                                                 | key                          | key_len | ref                            | rows  | filtered | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mofs      | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,index_mofs_on_hidden,index_mofs_on_volumeA3,index_mofs_on_atomicMass,index_mofs_on_volumeA3_and_atomicMass_and_hidden | index_mofs_on_hidden         | 1       | const                          | 60373 |    25.00 | Using where; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | isotherms | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,index_isotherms_on_mof_id                                                                                             | index_isotherms_on_mof_id    | 9       | mofdb2_prod_dump2.mofs.id      |     5 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | isodata   | NULL       | ref  | index_isodata_on_isotherm_id,index_isodata_on_gas_id                                                                          | index_isodata_on_isotherm_id | 9       | mofdb2_prod_dump2.isotherms.id |     3 |    41.45 | Using where; Distinct        |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------+
```

How can I speed up this query?
Is there a way to add an index that captures the mof->isotherm->isodata.gas_id relationship ? Eg. In postgres sql I could create a materialized view like this:

```
mof_id|gas_id
1|350
1|33
2|5
2|33
...
```

and then query that view. Can I achieve something similar with an index?

#### Schema

```
mysql> show create table mofs;
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| mofs  | CREATE TABLE `mofs` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hashkey` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `database_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `cif` mediumtext,
  `void_fraction` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `surface_area_m2g` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `surface_area_m2cm3` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `pld` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `lcd` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `pxrd` text,
  `pore_size_distribution` text,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `pregen_json` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `mofid` text,
  `mofkey` text,
  `hidden` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `atomicMass` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `volumeA3` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_rails_42b2867304` (`database_id`),
  KEY `index_mofs_on_hashkey` (`hashkey`),
  KEY `index_mofs_on_name` (`name`),
  KEY `index_mofs_on_hidden` (`hidden`),
  KEY `index_mofs_on_pld` (`pld`),
  KEY `index_mofs_on_lcd` (`lcd`),
  KEY `index_mofs_on_void_fraction` (`void_fraction`),
  KEY `index_mofs_on_surface_area_m2g` (`surface_area_m2g`),
  KEY `index_mofs_on_surface_area_m2cm3` (`surface_area_m2cm3`),
  KEY `mofid_exact_match_idx` (`mofid`(768)),
  KEY `mofkey_exact_match_idx` (`mofkey`(768)),
  KEY `index_mofs_on_volumeA3` (`volumeA3`),
  KEY `index_mofs_on_atomicMass` (`atomicMass`),
  KEY `index_mofs_on_batch_id` (`batch_id`),
  KEY `index_mofs_on_volumeA3_and_atomicMass_and_hidden` (`volumeA3`,`atomicMass`,`hidden`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_42b2867304` FOREIGN KEY (`database_id`) REFERENCES `databases` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_c2906db3ef` FOREIGN KEY (`batch_id`) REFERENCES `batches` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=167396 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table isotherms;
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table     | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| isotherms | CREATE TABLE `isotherms` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `doi` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `digitizer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `temp` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `simin` text,
  `adsorbate_forcefield_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `molecule_forcefield_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `mof_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `adsorption_units_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `pressure_units_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `composition_type_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `batch_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_isotherms_on_mof_id` (`mof_id`),
  KEY `index_isotherms_on_adsorption_units_id` (`adsorption_units_id`),
  KEY `index_isotherms_on_pressure_units_id` (`pressure_units_id`),
  KEY `index_isotherms_on_composition_type_id` (`composition_type_id`),
  KEY `fk_rails_8886e0d88b` (`adsorbate_forcefield_id`),
  KEY `fk_rails_180e64ceb3` (`molecule_forcefield_id`),
  KEY `index_isotherms_on_doi` (`doi`),
  KEY `index_isotherms_on_batch_id` (`batch_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_10527b19a8` FOREIGN KEY (`composition_type_id`) REFERENCES `classifications` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_180e64ceb3` FOREIGN KEY (`molecule_forcefield_id`) REFERENCES `forcefields` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_1b8cd34a98` FOREIGN KEY (`pressure_units_id`) REFERENCES `classifications` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_7931af24f5` FOREIGN KEY (`adsorption_units_id`) REFERENCES `classifications` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_8886e0d88b` FOREIGN KEY (`adsorbate_forcefield_id`) REFERENCES `forcefields` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_94b5964f6a` FOREIGN KEY (`mof_id`) REFERENCES `mofs` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_ea429d3060` FOREIGN KEY (`batch_id`) REFERENCES `batches` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6368886 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table isodata;
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table   | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| isodata | CREATE TABLE `isodata` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `isotherm_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `gas_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `pressure` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `loading` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `bulk_composition` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_isodata_on_isotherm_id` (`isotherm_id`),
  KEY `index_isodata_on_gas_id` (`gas_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_279fe04b2e` FOREIGN KEY (`isotherm_id`) REFERENCES `isotherms` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_b1baf3536c` FOREIGN KEY (`gas_id`) REFERENCES `gases` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17313801 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Your schema is unreadable. Provide CREATE TABLE for used tables as code-formatted text into the question.

Comment: Can you provide the schema definitions and the create index statements you've tried.

Comment: Please qualify all columns; what tables are `volumeA3` and `atomicMass` in?  What indexes do you have?

Comment: @Akina I have added this to the post.

Comment: @RickJames volumeA3 and atomicMass are floating point columns on the mofs table.

Comment: You can try removing the need for DISTINCT by using an `EXISTS` subquery. Something like: `SELECT mofs.*
FROM mofs
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM isotherms 
       INNER JOIN isodata ON isodata.isotherm_id = isotherms.id
  WHERE isotherms.mof_id = mofs.id
    AND isodata.gas_id IN (24)
)
  AND (volumeA3 IS NOT NULL AND atomicMass IS NOT NULL)
  AND mofs.hidden = FALSE ;`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ This yields similar runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

If `isotherms_mofs_join` is a many-to-many table, then it probably needs better indexes; see [*Many-to-many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Comment: I have removed isotherms_mofs_join from the query. It was an artifact of how my ORM wrote queries and is not a real table. The revised query should be clearer. Thank you for taking a look. The mofs -> isotherms relationship is 1-many.

Comment: @nlta - `isotherms.mof_id` takes care of that 1:many relationship.  And it is properly indexed and FK'd.